using the nuxt-svgo module, SVGs are not being loaded or "found"
I want to be able to import and use SVGs directly in a nuxt project i'm working on, I added the nuxt-svgo module, i place my SVGs in a svg directory in the assets directory and configured the nuxt-svgo or svgo in/through the nuxt.config.ts file to this:
svgo: { autoImportPath: '~/assets/svg/' }

however in another vue file where i try using a SVG like so:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { SvgoBackspace } from '#build/components';
</script>

<template>
  <SvgoBackspace class="w-7 inline" />
</template>

i get this error:

i have not tried much, just editing the nuxt.config.ts 'cos i'm kind of new to nuxt, and not sure what goes where

I am not sure about the whole # alias but maybe try it with a regular ~/mypath/tothe/file kind of approach: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#alias

@kissu based on the whole thing the module does - and what i understand by it - i shouldn't have to do that, as there's an autoImportPath option meaning the SVGs are auto imported

Then you can directly use SvgoBackspace with no imports. Why do you want to import it manually if it's already done for you automatically? Use it as you would use a regular Nuxt component.

@kissu I get IntelliSense suggestion while typing the SVG's name, I press Enter, and it gets the SVG from lord knows where

@kissu hold up, commenting out the import works, merci. i think the #build/components content are stub types. thanks again

@kissu however, i'm unable to do something like <component :is="key === 'del' ? SvgoBackspace : SvgoEyeClosed" />, then i get a <svg_name> is not defined error

You cannot use a dynamic component if I'm not mistaken but you could make a conditional and v-if one or the other.

By removing the import, OP achieved to have some working solution.
The module nuxt-svgo indeed imports the icons automatically thanks to autoImportPath, just like a usual Nuxt component would behave.
